# how to use dropdown box to filter the display/hide div element in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, dropdown, vue-composition-api, vue-directives

I am new to VueJS and trying to create a simple dropdown box to filter the display/hide of `div` but encounter some problems.

```html
<template>
  <select
    class="form-select"
    aria-label="Default select example"
    name="filter"
    @change="genderSelected(true)"
  >
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

Control display/hide of the div:

```html
<div v-if="gender === 'Male'">Male</div>

<div v-if="gender === 'Female'">Female</div>
```

Vue

```html
<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    const gender = ref("Male");
    const genderSelected = (pick) => {
      if (pick.value === "Male") {
        gender.value = "Male";
      } else if (pick.value == "Female") {
        gender.value = "Female";
      }
    };
    return {
      genderSelected,
      gender,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: You have not described the problem.  What is the expected behavior? What is the behavior you're seeing?  Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Thank you!

Comment: `<select>` is not a dropdown box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue with your code is that you are passing static value of `true` into your `genderSelected` function. So then boolean of `true` does not know what to do with `pick.value`.

Instead, you can do it like this:

```
    <select
      class="form-select"
      aria-label="Default select example"
      name="filter"
      @change="genderSelected" >
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
```

Just having function without parentheses will pass the `@change` event as first argument.

Or alternatively if you want to explicitly provide the event, pass [`$event`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#accessing-event-argument-in-inline-handlers) into function like so: `@change="genderSelected($event)"`

Then your function would be reduced to:

```
const genderSelected = (event) => { gender.value = event.target.value; };
```

That should get you working code.

As a bonus, you can trim your template a little bit by using this, which is equivalent of your sample code:

```
<div>{{ gender }}</div>
```

And you can skip having `genderSelected` method by just replacing line with `@change` with `v-model="gender"`, and then reduce your whole component down to:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>{{ gender }}</div>
    <select
      class="form-select"
      aria-label="Default select example"
      name="filter"
      v-model="gender"
    >
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {
    const gender = ref('Male');
    return {
      gender,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Here's a sandbox showing both approaches: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-s3erax?file=src/App.vue

Comment: Clear explanation. Thanks for it.